# Trouble connecting to Fusio (api-manager) on a shared server

Tags: php, rest, serve, ibm-api-management

I have a problem connecting to the [Fusio](https://www.fusio-project.org/about) interface (api-manager). I installed it in ftp on a shared server. Until then everything is fine, the database is well updated and I have access to the fusio graphical interface. It is when I have to connect to the GUI that it is blocked. I enter my credentials and just after, an alert tells me: "Your connection to this site is not private".

---

[Image of the second connection request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMlsj.jpg)

A little more details follow the comment @Luca Stucchi

I want to perform an installation using the mode: "[installation script](https://www.fusio-project.org/bootstrap)" (as explained in the documentation).

The API Manager is installed on a shared server, I can not use command lines.

This installation mode allows us to install via an ihm. During the installation, everything goes well. The database is well created and I have access to a login page.

But the problem starts now. When I enter my login information a pop-up appears, the message "Your connection to this site is not private" appears.

And I do not know how to avoid this popup blocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why do you see the error

The error message "Your Connection is Not Private" is displayed for various reasons:

- Invalid or non-trusted SSL certificate.
- Time is not synchronized between the server and the client.
- Issues related to browser cache.
- AntiVirus/Proxy service blocking or interfering traffic.
- Wrong DNS settings.

## How to overcome

- if it's a non-trusted SSL certificate: try to install it to your Trusted Root store.
- invalid SSL certificate: if possible - re-create the SSL certificate on the server.
- make sure that the SSL certificate it not already expired or that its validity *starts in the future*.
- Sync your Clock on both sides (server and client).
- Clear SSL state: open `Internet Explorer` -> `Internet Options` -> `Content` tab -> `Certificates` -> `Clear SSL state` button.
- Clear browser cache (Cached images,Files, and Data)
- Turn off (temporarly) your AntiVirus/Proxy.
- Use some public DNS like google's (8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4).

[source](https://helpdeskgeek.com/help-desk/how-to-fix-your-connection-is-not-private-error-in-google-chrome/) for most of the ideas.

P.S.
I'd suggest adding a code sample to get more precise answers...

Comment: Thank you very much @itsho, I will test all of that! I will come back here to tell you if it works. If it does not work, I will post more details (code example). Have a good day!